# Where can I find or add the _AppStart & _PageStart in ASP.NET projects?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-deployment, razor-pages

Let me start off by saying I've seen a *StackOverflow* question related to this but there's no question like this I want to ask!

In my learning journey of the framework **ASP.NET**, I find a little problem. When I create any new **ASP.NET** project using the *dotnetCLI*. by standard the projects are missing two files that i'm looking for the *_AppStart* and *_PageStart*. Where can i find them or how can i add them?
**Thanks**

Comment: You will have to create them yourself: [Adding Website Startup Code for ASP.NET Web Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/ui-layouts-and-themes/18-customizing-site-wide-behavior#adding-website-startup-code-for-aspnet-web-pages) "... You can do this by creating a page named _AppStart.cshtml in the root of the site."

Comment: As you have used CLI then is your project is for Dot Net framework or Dot net core. If it is dot net framework then one suggestion don't use that. Use dot net core only.

Comment: I tried by adding them manually but i get errors and some razor code not working like @RenderPage() method. They are deprecated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The _AppStart and _PageStart files belong to the old ASP.NET Web Pages framework. They are not supported in the new Razor Pages framework, which is what you are using when you create applications using the CLI.

The equivalent to _AppStart in Razor Pages is the Program.cs file (.NET 6 onwards) or the Configure method in Startup (ASP.NET Core 2 - 5). The replacement for the _PageStart file is _ViewStart.

The Web Pages framework is more or less dead. Two of its four pillars have been deprecated (SQL CE and WebMatrix) and the recommendation these days is that you use Razor Pages instead.

https://www.learnrazorpages.com

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: So! should I learn the ASP.NET Web Pages framework or avoid it and go to ASP.NET Razor?

Comment: @RsAek Avoid Web Pages and learn Razor Pages instead.

Comment: You should of course consider MVC, and razor pages. However, razor does require a good high power and resource intensive server to run. Probably more then even what web forms requires. Webforms can be good for work - since boatloads of existing sites do still use the older web forms. And JUST last year - they updated web forms to support hot code load, live browser preview (with new edge/chrome engine), and a whole boatload of extra features. So they ARE STILL adding boatloads of new features to web forms - they are still common and supported - just not the future.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal Do you have any cites to support your claim that Razor requires more resources than Web Forms?